# Comparing formidable pro and gravity forms

Tags: forms, plugin-recommendation, plugin-gravity-forms

Has anyone come across any good reviews/comparisons of gravity forms and formidable pro? I am trying to find more information on both.

I have a couple of sites that need several forms for adding items to our physical collections, leave requests and reserving specific rooms and resources and the like. I need something that will email form submissions as well as store entries in a database and which I can use to generate reports.

Any information or personal experience with either of these or other options would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just begun using Gravity Forms but I've used Formidable quite a lot. My biggest complaints about Formidable is the way it handles upgrades. If you have a 'Pro' account, when an upgrade is available you have to go through a multi-step, not very intuitive upgrade process every time.

Other than that, so far Formidable has worked very well for me. It doesn't have all the 'extras' that Gravity Forms seems to offer, like MailChimp integration, but that hasn't been that big a deal. And, it's far cheaper in the long term with a one-time, unlimited license for $99 (when I bought). Gravity Forms makes you renew every year or lose support.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Formidable, but I used Gravity all the time and I can vouch that it is one of the most solid WordPress products I've ever used. I've stretched its limits many times. The only thing I'm not sure it has that you're looking for is reports. I saw that Formidable shows graphs for poll results -- Gravity doesn't have anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Both are great.  Formidable is cheaper and better for the novice wordpress developer, where Gravity is for more advanced developers.  It really depends on the project you are tasked with.

**Gravity**
Gravity has a better community on the web and documentation on hooks and filters built into the system.  It also integrates well with different frameworks.  There is not included styling, so you need to search the forum for the style you want.  Also, gravity's list type and product types are unique.

**Formidable**
Formidable has the data from entries and edit capabilities built in without havin to code or use an additional plugin.  I would agree with Michelle about the Pro upgrade process.  Formidable's support page is absolutely incredible.